# Pricing for SQL database/ per SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql

I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong about Price Tiers and SQL Databases.

Is the price paid per server or per database? I thought it was per database, só if I get a client, they can pay X per as a sample a 10 DTU sql server, and inside I can create 2 or 3 databases to work togheter inside the 10DTU limite.

Or if I ge a biger client with the same mdel, then this client can pai more DTU like 3o ou 40 DTU by his server tih 2 or 3 databases inside.

But today I created a new database for a pilot that already has 2 databases (one for production and another for development and tests) and I found that appears that each database inside the same server has his own independent payment price.... elevating the price per 3 if a client needs his data separated or if wee need to create a side copy database per auditing or for a restore, the cost will incresing?

I’m trying to understand if I pay per SQL database or per SQL Server. Lets suppose I have:

1 sql server on basic bill plan 5 DTU with: database1 database2 database3
1 sql server on basic bill plan 10 DTU with: database1 database2 database3
Let’s suppose they are 24 h per day all the month. So I will pay 3 * 5DTU + 3 * 10DTU or 1 * 5DTU + 1 * 5DTU?

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL is charged per database, not per server. You will be charged for the size and DTU you select for each DB.

However, you can also use [elastic pools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool), which sounds like it will fit your use case better. Here you create an elastic pool and select the size and performance of the pool, then you create databases inside the pool that share those resources. You are only charged for the cost of the pool.